# Docker - Using localhost for to access running container

Tags: linux, docker, port

This command below: 
`docker run -p 8000:8000 -t panels2`
Which I am running should apparently allow me to run my application  localhost on port 8000 locally.
In the docker terminal when running ‘docker ps’ I see:
`0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp`

Dockerfile look this:

```
EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python3.6", "/app/manage.py", "runserver"]
```

How to get access to localhost:8000?

Comment: And your question?

Comment: How to get access to localhost:8000?

Comment: What you see when opening locally in browser `http://localhost:8000/`?

Comment: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and sometimes ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: with `docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -t panels2`, are you getting error?

Comment: I got just long container ID. I thing that problem is with mapping, but I don't know how can I identity it

Comment: `docker logs your_container` to see what happend? Seems django, paste django startup infomation. Also confirm you container still alive?

Comment: I resolve problem by set ip on 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is set ip on 0.0.0.0 not 127.0.0.1(work inside container) because when we create a bridge then automatically ports are mapping on 0.0.0.0 ip even if we set 127.0.0.1 for application.